# Is 'we thought your pharmacy would be interested' wrong?

Tags: errors

Let's say I'm a person who's sending an e-mail to a person or a company who owns a pharmacy - I'm trying to promote my medical device to them. Would the following be considered wrong or "bad" English?

> We thought your pharmacy would be interested in our product

If the above *is* wrong, how can I paraphrase the whole thing so it becomes right?

Comment: It is perhaps not _wrong_, per se; but in my experience, pharmacies rarely have feelings or interests.

Comment: It's not particularly wrong, although the thought may have been

Comment: @Janus The metonymic use of (for example) 'your pharmacy' for 'the people at the pharmacy owned by you' is of course well established. But surely OP is here soliciting the views / the favour of the owner.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It’s not the metonymy itself that borderline bothers me here—but there’s something about using such a metonomous entity in too directly active a fashion that makes it jar a little. “Our product may be of interest to your pharmacy” doesn’t jar at all, while “Your pharmacy has been drinking too much after work” jars quite a bit. The example in this question is somewhere in between, jarring a _little_ bit, but not enough that it’s really a problem. (To my ear, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this phrasing would be suitable: "We have a product that might appeal to your customers."

Comment: Makes more sense, but changes what OP says he's trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the use of "would" is rather assertive, and as such will cause the recipient to either pay close attention or dismiss the claim. The alternative, I think, is "might".

Actually, I think that if you're going to use "would", you should use the present tense, and replace "would" with "will".